# magento puts a random email in the cc field of transnational emails

Tags: email, customer-account, ce-1.9.2.1

About two days ago, i installed an extension, then have removed it. The people who made the extension say, their extension hasn't caused the problem but our customers have been contacting us to say that the email they got for their order is not theirs. 
when i looked i noticed that there is a random email put in all the transnational emails.

i upgraded to magento 1.9.2.1 but it is still happening. I removed all the extension files that I have installed to no avail.

i had custom email templates, now i put everything back to the default templates and that also didn't help.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is it the same email address on all the emails? If so, have you tried grep-ing your code for that email address? Have you tried looking in your admin panel to make sure that it's not configured to add that email address to those emails?

Comment: No, it's a random email picked up from previous orders. It's normally customers who get "other clients" emails notice the issue since it's not their own order. They get the emails by having their emails in CC field.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the issue by deleting all the rows in the email queue tables:
core_email_queue
core_email_queue_recipients

I didn't know that starting 1.9.1.0 emails are queue and then sent out.

***** Update:** This has not fixed the problem. Our customers were again getting random emails. I will stop the entire new queue process and will see how that turns out.